# Bash Procesos ejecutandose hace mas de 2 horas

Tags: linux

como puedo hacer para detectar procesos que se estan ejecutando hace mas de 2 horas?

Se que tengo que ejecutar ps -aux pero no doy a la tecla para poder mostrar solo los procesos que tienen mas de dos horas de ejecucion.

Me podran ayudar?

Answer (score 0):

El comando `ps aux` es muy genérico, te va a listar todos los procesos en ejecución con todas las columnas por defecto, tal vez quieras probar algo más breve:

```
ps -e -o pid,etimes,comm | awk '{if($2>7200) print $0}'
```

En resumen:

- [ps](https://man.archlinux.org/man/ps.1.en): Comando para reportar instántaneas (snapshots) de procesos en ejecución

  - `-e`: Opción para listar todos los procesos
  - `-o`: Opción para elegir el formato deseado (columnas separadas por coma)

    - `pid`: ID de proceso
    - `etimes`: Tiempo (en segundos) desde que se inició el proceso
    - `comm`: Comando que se usó para ejecutar, sin argumentos. Si también quieres ver los argumentos, reemplaza por `command`
- `|`: Canalizar un comando a otro, es decir, que la salida será enviada a ese otro comando para ser procesada
- [awk](https://man.archlinux.org/man/awk.1p): Comando para escanear y procesar lenguaje por patrones

  - `'{if($2>7200) print $0}'`: Ejecutará una instrucción cuando se cumpla la condición que está entre paréntesis

    - `$2`: La salida se separa por cualquier cantidad e espacios y se toma la segunda columna, que corresponde a `etimes`; explicación con ejemplo:

      - `$0` - Es la línea completa
      - `$1` - Es la primera columna, `pid`
      - `$2` - Es la segunda columna, `etimes`
      - `$3` - Es la tercera columna, `comm`
    - `>7200`: En cada hora hay 3600 segundos, entonces compara si el tiempo de ejecución es mayor que dos horas
    - `print $0`: Imprime toda la línea del elemento que cumplió con la condición

**Edición:** No sé si funcione en tu sistema, pero puedes probar con:

```
ps -e -o pid,etime,comm --sort=start_time | grep -v grep | awk '{if(+substr($0,12,2) >= 2) print $0}'
```

Básicamente, toma la salida y busca los primeros números de la hora de inicio, si es mayor o igual que 2, muestra el proceso.

Comment: Al ejecutar el comando me da el siguiente mensaje: 
ps -e -o pid,etimes,comm | awk '{if($2>7200) print $0}'
ERROR: Unknown user-defined format specifier "etimes".

La version del ps es procps version 3.2.8

Comment: Ahi ejecute el comando pero no entiendo la salida,

Siendo las 18:39 ejecuto el comando y me devuelve lo siguiente:

ps -e -o pid,etime,comm | awk '{if($2>7200) print $0}'
  PID     ELAPSED COMMAND
24002  8-18:39:48 postgres
24221  8-09:09:42 postgres

Comment: @pepeargento, revisa el final de la respuesta, agregué otra opción.